# Cloudinary Nuxt Module: Unknown element cld-image

Tags: nuxt.js, cloudinary

I am using the [@NuxtJS/Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.nuxtjs.org/) module like so:

```html
              <cld-image
                :public-id="post.photoURL"
                class="rounded-circle me-1"
                type="fetch"
                width="40"
                height="40"
                crop="fill"
                gravity="auto"
                fetch-format="auto"
                quality="auto"
                :alt="`${post.displayName}'s avatar image`"
              />
```

It works fine in my app. However, in browser console I get the following Vue Hydration Warning:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 
        
       [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

I do have the module added in my nuxt.config.js file like so:

`modules: ['@nuxtjs/cloudinary'],`

And, when I run an HTML validation, I get the following HTML validation error shown in my text editor like so:

`error  Unknown element <cld-image>`

OK, so do I need to manually import the `cld-image` component locally? If so, what is the purpose of having the cloudinary module in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: Is the error coming from the `<cld-image>` tag? What if you close it with a second tag? Did you do any additional configuration with the module?

Comment: Is the issue here related to your bug? https://github.com/nuxt-community/cloudinary-module/issues/52#issuecomment-747353113 I know I faced it once and it's still not fixed. Otherwise, you can also wrap it into a `client-only` of course.

Comment: I tried to close it with a second tag -- same issue. Yes, I'm the person that posted that issue on github. Wrapping it in client-only fixes it, and I'm good with that --don't need it for SSR since its an avatar image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix that with a `client-only` tag.

Otherwise, maybe try the cloudinary integration of the Nuxt image module: https://image.nuxtjs.org/providers/cloudinary/